# Two containers sharing vertical height dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have two containers which need to share their parent's height, but the second container is added dynamically on demand. There can be a lot of content in both containers so the opportunity to scroll must be given.

I have a working solution for a 50/50 share, but I wonder if it's possible to share the height dynamically.

```
.wrapper__container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.inside__container {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Part of the wrapper component render method:

```
render() {
  const maxHeight = this.state.showDetails ? '50%' : '100%';
  const minHeight = this.state.showDetails ? '50%' : '100%';
  return (
    <div className="wrapper__container">
      <Config 
        itemsGreen={this.state.itemsGreen}
        itemsRed={this.state.itemsRed}
        changeItemCount={this.changeItemCount}
      />
      <Container
        itemCount={this.state.itemsGreen}
        className="inside__container"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          maxHeight,
          minHeight
        }}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
      {this.state.showDetails && <Container
        itemCount={this.state.itemsRed}
        className="inside__container"
        style={{ 
          backgroundColor: 'tomato',
          maxHeight,
          minHeight
        }}
      />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've setup a [codepen](https://codepen.io/marcklei/pen/KvKZaB), where you can change the count of items to test the behaviour. Click on the green container to show the red one.

At least it would be a good solution to limit the green container to a max-height 50% and let the red container take up the rest. If the green, for example, is only 20% the red can take 80%.

In a perfect world this should be possible without js calculations but if someone has an idea to calculate this (only react/vanilla).

Target browser is IE11.

**Edit**: Added a new [Pen](https://codepen.io/marcklei/pen/EvxRXZ) which is broken, but shows the desired flexible behaviour when there are only a few items.

Comment: Which element is intended to scroll? You have to pick **one** otherwise this is not solveable with CSS.

Comment: They both should be scrollable, do I need to calculate heights to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

Each time the outer container is rendered, you need to get the height of the container and divide it by two, then apply that number as the height of each of your internal divs. Like so (using jquery):

```
var $two = $('<div id="two"></div>');
var $three = $('<div id="three"></div>');
$('#container').append($two);
$('#container').append($three);
var h = $('#one').height();
console.log((h/2)-1)
if($('#two').height() < ((h/2)-1)) {
  $('#three').height( ( h-$('#two').height() ) - 1 );
} else {
   $('#two').height((h/2)-1);
   $('#three').height((h/2)-1);
}
```

Comment: Am I worng or does this calculation get me to a 50/50 soultion as well. I'd like to calculate the shares depended on each other.

Comment: I have a working solution for a 50/50 share, but I wonder if it's possible to share the height dynamically. .... If the green, for example, is only 20% the red can take 80%. What is not clear? So I can improve the question.

Comment: I've edited the answer to better suit your question.